# Parse indefinite ammount of variables from JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am currently trying to load an indefinite amount of variables from a JSON array, and have no idea how to do this.

My JSON file is as follows:

```
{"commands": [
    {"cmd": "hello", "params": "%u", "output": "hello %s!"},
    {"cmd": "ping", "params": "", "output": "pong!"},
    {"cmd": "test", "params": "%ul", "output": "test %s.."}
]}
```

I am using the GSON library from Google.

Would I have to manually parse each command, or is there a way to achieve this with `gson.fromJson()`?

Comment: Assuming your JSON is actually valid (unlike what I see here), yes, `gson.fromJson()` can parse a JSON array such as `"commands"` into a `List<Command>`, for example.

Comment: I am somewhat unfamiliar with JSON, in what way is it not valid?

Comment: You are missing double quotes around the field names

Comment: Just looks like some typos, mostly. The key-value pairs should be separated with commas and the keys should be in quotes. For example, `{"cmd": "test", "params": "%ul", "output": "test %s.."}`

Comment: gson is pretty lenient, unquoted keys don't cause any problems. The only thing that will cause problems is the missing `,` after `"test"` in the third element.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited and fixed the JSON errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a wrapper object containing an array or a collection of Command objects as a model for the deserialization process:

**Command.java**

```
public class Command{

  private String cmd;

  private String params;

  private String output;

 // Getters and setters

}
```

**CommandWrapper.java**

```
public class CommandWrapper{

  private List<Command> commands;

  // Getters and setters

}
```

And then in your class you can deserialize the JSON this way:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 CommandWrapper wrapper = gson.fromJson(myInputJson, CommandWrapper.class);
```

And get your commands as a list.

Comment: public List<Command> getCommands(){return this.commands;} if I have understood your question

Comment: Sorry, I realized I meant the setter and not the getter, and that I knew how to do them. However, I have tried my own code for setting and am getting a blank list after gson.fromJson(...) How should the setter look?

Comment: Public voi setCommands (List <Command> commands){this.commands = commands;}

Answer (score 2):

If the number is **really** indefinite; you might want to look into creating a Java8 **stream** from your input; as streams can be (theoretically) without an end.

But probably you should simply return a List of some specific class of yours that nicely "wraps" around the JSON data in your file.